# Recycler view taking entire screen.Not displaying my UI element above it

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to add an Imageview above my recycler view but the recycler view ends up taking the whole screen and doesn't display my image view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".AccountFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/blogListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/acc"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="146dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="86dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Rinith, remember to consider giving and example of what you're trying to achieve or the current state of your implementation so people can get the context and spot an error if there's such and welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: @Panthro done. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to the ImageView:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

so it is at the top of the parent layout.
If you think that these attributes:

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="146dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="86dp"
```

affect the position of the `ImageView`, then you are wrong. 
Any attribute from the `tools` namespace is valid only at design time.
So you might as well remove them.
Also you might want to center the `ImageView` horizontally:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Comment: Hi forpas. I updated the changes to the ImageView.. It still doesn't work.The recycler view takes up the whole space.Can't find the ImageView anywhere

Comment: The ImageView is on top,  and since its height and width are wrap_content, if there is no image set for it then its size is 0 so it's not visible.

Comment: I tried doing the changes.But nothing except the recycler view is being displayed. I tried placing the recycler view in a separate relative layout as well

Comment: In design view, do you see the ImageView with the drawable `acc`?

Comment: Yes in design view its visible.

Comment: Is the layout you posted the exact layout you use or not? Set for a test:         `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="100dp"` and check if the ImageView is visible.

Comment: Hi, yes it is the exact layout I use. I applied the changes, the ImageView is visible in designView but still not in while using the application

Comment: Is there a case that at runtime it does not contain any image? If it is empty then it is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

hi try to set this as i checked its working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_play" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/blogListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Haroon, I have tried this already but it doesn't seem to work. I'm unable to figure out this.

Answer (score 0):

A RelativeLayout places every element at the start of the screen (0,0). In your case the ImageView is behind the RecyclerView. If you need to display RecyclerView below ImageView, opt for LinearLayout instead, with orientation set to vertical.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AccountFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/acc" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/blogListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try the above code and let me know if it works.